# Meta names differently in hamburger menu on app and web

Tags: feature-request, android-app, top-bar, site-name

Here is a view of my hamburger menu on the web (Meta.SE is identified as "Meta Stack Exchange"):

[image]

Here is a view of my hamburger menu on the (Android) app (Meta.SE is identified as "Meta"):

[image]

There seems to be no need to only use Meta (for concern if "Meta Stack Exchange" might be too long); can we make these two entries consistent?

Comment: If "Geographic Information Systems" is not too long, then neither is "Meta Stack Exchange".